# Deploy a feature with zero downtime

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

How do you deploy a feature with zero downtime in Kubernetes?

kubectl run nginx --image=nginx # creates a deployment
○ → kubectl get deploy
NAME    DESIRED  CURRENT UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE AGE
nginx   1  1 1            0 7s
Now let’s assume we are going to update the nginx image

kubectl set image deployment nginx nginx=nginx:1.15 # updates the image
Now when we check the replica sets

kubectl get replicasets # get replica sets
NAME               DESIRED CURRENT READY   AGE
nginx-65899c769f   0 0 0       7m
nginx-6c9655f5bb   1 1 1       13s
From the above, we can notice that one more replica set was added and then the other replica set was brought down

kubectl rollout status deployment nginx

## check the status of a deployment rollout

kubectl rollout history deployment nginx

## check the revisions in a deployment

○ → kubectl rollout history deployment nginx
deployment.extensions/nginx
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         
2

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is but you should look into strategy of deployment in kubernetes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use strategy as rolling update with max surge and max unavailable defined

for morer information go here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/